# How to do multiple operations in single stored procedure in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Is it possible to do multiple operations in a single stored procedure in cosmos Db with bounded execution? 
I have to perform below operations in a single stored procedure

1. A new record to be inserted
2. Few records to be deleted
3. Update Operation to be performed

How can data consistency be maintained with transaction support in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Cosmos DB stored procedures work transactionally, within a single partition of a single collection. So, as long as your inserts, deletes, and updates (replacements, to be more accurate) are all within a single partition, they would all be handled transactionally within a single stored procedure call.

Comment: Hi David,

those all operations are related to single partition only but how to overcome bounded execution in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Ramakrishna Reddy,

As David mentioned, transactions can only be achieved within a partition in a collection. see documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency. I have the experience of a time when multiple collections were merged into one collection for the ability to achieve transactions. You might need to do the same thing as well.

There are examples to achieve transactions here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs.md of how to create stored procedures.

In your particular situation, you will probably need to write a transaction that takes an array of items to upsert, and an array of items to delete. You can find an example of a deletion transaction here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/blob/master/samples/clientside-transactions/DocDBClientBulk/DocDBClientBulk/bulkDelete.js

Alternatively, you can use Transactional batch in .NET SDK that Cosmos now supports.  In addition to transactions support, you can see other upcoming long-awaited updates in this blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/whats-new-in-azure-cosmos-db-nov-2019/. However, I am unclear whether it supports the deletion that you are seeking. I haven't gotten a chance to play with it. Maybe you can share when you figure it out!

Comment: Hi Rene

all the operations I mentioned are related to single partition only. I am worried about bounded execution if i have more data to delete or update in future

Comment: Transactional batch doesn't support multiple records delete or update

Comment: Thank you for confirming that transactional batch does not support deletion.If you have a lot of records to delete that might not complete in time, you might consider using the continuation key strategy, but you will lose transactions capability. What are the implications if some of the data is not deleted in the same transaction? You will need to know (or estimate the worst case) the exact size of your updates and deletions and test them.

Comment: If I increase the throughput by calculating the worst-case scenario, will this issue be resolved

Comment: I am not quite sure but even if the issue would be resolved, I would personally not recommend it. If you do that, you run into a position where you consume a lot of RUs and hard for you to scale. Stored procedures already consume additional Request Units (RU/s) already. Have you considered redesigning your models? I can't say much to how it would look like since I do not have the complete scenario.

Comment: Actually I am merging the tables to achieve the transaction capability and all my operations combined (one record insert, multiple records deletion and single record update) won't contain more than 100 records so how can I achieve this in a better manner. Any architectural advice is appreciated.